# Query only displaying one result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have the following query that all along I thought my while loop was not working, but it turns out my query is only outputting one record.

```sql
SELECT up.ordering, u.id, u.username, up.playername 
FROM users AS u 
INNER JOIN playersByUser AS up ON u.id = up.userid 
WHERE u.group IN (3,4,5)
ORDER BY up.ordering
```

It should be outputting several and I am unsure why it is only getting one. I'm trying to select the id's from both the users and playersByUser table where the group is 5 in the users table. Then output the username.

playersByUser

```sql
CREATE TABLE `playersByUser` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `userid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `playername` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `ordering` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `userid` (`userid`),
 CONSTRAINT `playersByUser_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

users

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `firstname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `lastname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `phone_number` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `salt` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `joined` datetime NOT NULL,
 `group` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=95 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_c
```

The data that can be used is this:

users

```sql
id  firstname lastname   email            phone_number username  password salt   joined    group
1   name1     lastname1  email@email.com  555-555-5555 testSQL   fdfdf     acc     9-3-15   5
2   name2     lastname2  email2@email.com 555-555-5556 testSQL2  fdfdf     dcc     9-3-15   5
```

playersByUser

```sql
id userid playername ordering
1    1        Bob       1
2    2        Dave      1
```

Comment: No, it doesn't fail, when I quote it, it does the same thing.

Comment: You don't even have a statement to fetch results but *prepare* only. Are you fetching it row by row? Also consider using sqlfiddle to save up on time for those who try to answer.

Comment: I am testing this in phpmyadmin as my loop and fetch is working. It is outputting what the sql pulls, which is only one record. My query is the issue. I have never used sqlfiddle.

Comment: If the problem is `SQL` why not post just the query and tables? And we need the data inside the tables also what is the result of that query to see what is the problem. Make the question as simple as posible  [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, I thought this question was simply wrote. The data can be anything. Just the users and playersByUser table needs to have at least two records. In the users table there needs to be two users with the group of 5. I will update my question.

Comment: Updated my question to show data.

Comment: I try to format the sample but still feel incomplete, could you take a look?. You need provide Sample, Current Output, and Desire Output.

Comment: The reason I had group over the number 5's is because that is the group. The salt can be anything. Also joined is irrelevant and can be anything as that is just a date.

Comment: I just try to edit in a way is easy to read. Please fix any error i made.

Comment: Fixed. But that is all it is. No matter if I have group 3 or 4 in there as well nothing else shows up with the query.

Comment: Everything inside of the playersByUser should be outputting or being selected, based on the group I am wanting from the users table and then the username should output from the users table and then the playername and ordering from the playersByUser table.

Comment: Given the sample rows your provided, your query does work as intended. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa07c4/1 <-- site is having some problems right now...  Perhaps more representative sample rows are needed.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski You are correct. My query was correct. I just discovered it, I was doing something really dumb and had the wrong group id's in my table. Thank you everyone and I apologize!

Comment: @Becky Glad you got it sorted out. Since neither of your questions has upvoted answers and the contents were a red herring, you might consider deleting them.

Comment: Your sql-query is working fine. Please refer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90ca7/1 for details

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried renaming your users.group field? also have you tried a left join in case data doesn't exist on your joined table?

```
SELECT playersByUser.ordering, users.id, users.username, playersByUser.playername 
   FROM users, playersByUser where users.id = playersByUser.userid 
   AND `users.group` IN (3,4,5)
   ORDER BY playersByUser.ordering
```

works fine for me in phpMyAdmin

Comment: This threw an error, so I did this.. users.`group`. It still only brought up the one user.